# NSTokenField completion list style

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, rubymotion

I'm a beginner in OSX development so I hope my question will find a solution here.

I have an `NSTokenField` in my app and I implemented the `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` method.

Everything works fine but the present result look like this :

[image]

What I would like is to make it look like this: (similar to the completion in the Mail app)

[image]

Which means that I would like the completion list to take all the NSTokenField width.
Using the **Accessibility Inspector**, I can see that the hierarchy corresponding to the first sreenshot is:

`AXScrollArea -> AXList -> AXTextField`

while the one corresponding to the second screenshot is:

`AXScrollArea -> AXTable -> AXRow:AXTableRow -> AXTextField`

So I suppose I have to use an `NSTableView` to display the completion list, but I don't know how to achieve this. Does anybody know how is that possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

At least 2 people suggested that I implement the `tokenField:menuForRepresentedObject:` method and define the menu width with the appropriate `NSMenu` property. But this method is used to define a menu for a given token and I already implemented it:

```
  def tokenField(tokenField, menuForRepresentedObject:representedObject)
    theMenu = NSMenu.alloc.initWithTitle("Email address context menu")
    item_0 = theMenu.insertItemWithTitle('add_to_address_book'.localized, action:'add_to_address_book', keyEquivalent:"", atIndex:0)
    item_0.setTarget(self)
    item_1 = theMenu.insertItemWithTitle('new_message'.localized, action:'new_message', keyEquivalent:"", atIndex:1)
    item_1.setTarget(self)
    theMenu
  end
```

Which gives me something like this:

[image: tokenField:menuForRepresentedObject:]

Something great but not what I am asking here.